# UIScrollView scrollEnabled does not stop two finger gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

The `UIScrollView` property `scrollEnabled` stops one finger gestures but multiple finger gestures seem still to work albeit with the error message

> Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since
>   gesture recognizer is not active.

Is this bad? Am I doing something wrong? `canCancelContentTouches` seems to stop the action but the error message remains. Can I thus ask

1. should I worry about the the error message?
2. is `canCancelContentTouches` the best way to cancel all scroll actions?
3. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but basically scrollEnabled is only designed to stop scrolling  of the scrollview itself, not interaction with content inside the scrollview.

If you want to stop people from interacting with content within the scrollview, using a UIGestureRecognizer and its delegate to intercept the gestures and ignore them seem like the way to go.

Comment: this makes a lt of sense and I apologise for the poor wording of my question. I do indeed have other gesture recognisers defined to pick up tap and rotation events ignored by the scroll view, and a UIButton floating above the view to run scrolling on and off but commenting out the gesture recognisers does not seem to work. I could try selectively adding and removing pan and pinch controllers the intercept the gestures that way. It just seems strange to see this behaviour in the basic version of the code with nothing added in.